# How to use scala strings in list-like pattern matching

Tags: string, scala, generics, implicit, trie

So I was reading up about how scala lets you treat string as a sequence of chars through its implicit mechanism. I created a generic `Trie` class for a general element type and wanted to use it's `Char` based implementation with string like syntax.

```
import collection.mutable
import scala.annotation.tailrec

case class Trie[Elem, Meta](children: mutable.Map[Elem, Trie[Elem, Meta]], var metadata: Option[Meta] = None) {

  def this() = this(mutable.Map.empty)
  @tailrec
  final def insert(item: Seq[Elem], metadata: Meta): Unit = {
    item match {
      case Nil =>
        this.metadata = Some(metadata)
      case x :: xs =>
        children.getOrElseUpdate(x, new Trie()).insert(xs, metadata)
    }
  }

  def insert(items: (Seq[Elem], Meta)*): Unit = items.foreach { case (item, meta) => insert(item, meta) }

  def find(item: Seq[Elem]): Option[Meta] = {
    item match {
      case Nil => metadata
      case x :: xs => children.get(x).flatMap(_.metadata)
    }
  }
}


object Trie extends App {
  type Dictionary = Trie[Char, String]
  val dict = new Dictionary()

  dict.insert( "hello", "meaning of hello")
  dict.insert("hi", "another word for hello")
  dict.insert("bye", "opposite of hello")
  println(dict)
}
```

Weird thing is, it compiles fine but gives error on running:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: hello (of class scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString)
    at Trie.insert(Trie.scala:11)
    at Trie$.delayedEndpoint$com$inmobi$data$mleap$Trie$1(Trie.scala:34)
    at Trie$delayedInit$body.apply(Trie.scala:30)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Trie$.main(Trie.scala:30)
    at Trie.main(Trie.scala)
```

It's able to implicitly convert String to WrappedString, but that doesn't match the `::`. Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `startsWith` as follows:

```
val s = "ThisIsAString"
s match {
   case x if x.startsWith("T") => 1
   case _ => 0
}
```

Or convert your String to List of chars with `toList`

```
scala>     val s = "ThisIsAString"
s: String = ThisIsAString

scala> s.toList
res10: List[Char] = List(T, h, i, s, I, s, A, S, t, r, i, n, g)
```

An then use it as any other `List`

```
s.toList match {
  case h::t => whatever
  case _ => anotherThing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert method declares item to be a `Seq`, but your pattern match only matches on `List`.  A string can be implicitly converted to a `Seq[Char]`, but it isn't a `List`.  Use a pattern match on `Seq` instead of `List` using `+:`.

```
  @tailrec
  final def insert(item: Seq[Elem], metadata: Meta): Unit = {
    item match {
      case Seq() =>
        this.metadata = Some(metadata)
      case x +: xs =>
        children.getOrElseUpdate(x, new Trie()).insert(xs, metadata)
    }
  }
```

The same applies to your find method.